# Not getting the output for splitting the text files in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, split

I have been using the following code to split my text file into two files.My original file only consists of 20 lines which i am trying to split into 2 files.Even when the script runs and i get the message at the end saying that the process is complete i can't see any splitted files at the output location.Please tell me what's the problem in the code;I am new to vbscript so please help me.Thanks in advance :)

```
Dim  Counter
Const InputFile = "C:\Cs.txt"
Const OutputFile = "C:\Users\rmehta\Desktop"
Const RecordSize = 10
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (InputFile, ForReading)
Counter = 0
FileCounter = 0
Set objOutTextFile = Nothing

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
if Counter = 0 Or Counter = RecordSize Then
    Counter = 0
    FileCounter = FileCounter + 1
    if Not objOutTextFile is Nothing then objOutTextFile.Close
    Set objOutTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( OutputFile & "_" & FileCounter & ".txt", ForWriting, True)
end if
strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
objOutTextFile.WriteLine(strNextLine)
Counter = Counter + 1
Loop
objTextFile.Close
objOutTextFile.Close
Msgbox "Split process complete"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave out all the spurious fat (the Textstream has a line counter and the first output file can be opened before the loop), you get

```
  Option Explicit
  Const cnSize = 10
  Dim oFS   : Set oFS   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sDir  : sDir      = "..\testdata\18308970"
  Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn  = oFS.OpenTextFile(oFS.BuildPath(sDir, "all.txt"))
  Dim nFCnt : nFCnt     = 0
  Dim tsOut : Set tsOut = oFS.CreateTextFile(oFS.BuildPath(sDir, nFCnt & "-part.txt"))
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     If 0 = tsIn.Line Mod cnSize Then
        tsOut.Close
        nFCnt     = nFCnt + 1
        Set tsOut = oFS.CreateTextFile(oFS.BuildPath(sDir, nFCnt & "-part.txt"))
     End If
     tsOut.WriteLine tsIn.ReadLine()
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
  tsOut.Close
```

That this 'works' - if you have the folder, input file, and permissions - is obvious. In your code, the problem

```
>> Const OutputFile = "C:\Users\rmehta\Desktop"
>> FileCounter = 0
>> WScript.Echo OutputFile & "_" & FileCounter & ".txt"
>>
C:\Users\rmehta\Desktop_0.txt
```

is is deeply hidden.

Comment: Worked with a small change of keeping cnSize=11 ... Thanks a lot!!! Very useful :)